# constexpr with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a custom function for finding minimum value:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T minimumval(const T& a, const T& b, const Ts&... t) {
    const auto m = a < b ? a : b;
    if constexpr(sizeof...(t) > 0) {
        return minimumval(m, t...);
    }
    return m;
}
```

This works perfect. However, the moment I remove `constexpr`, it chokes with:

```
<source>:14:26: error: no matching function for call to 'minimumval(const int&)'
   14 |         return minimumval(m, t...);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:3: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class ... Ts> T minimumval(const T&, const T&, const Ts& ...)'
   11 | T minimumval(const T& a, const T& b, const Ts&... t) {
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

And I then need to override the function with a basecase to get it working.

```
template<typename T>
T minimumval(const T& val) {
    return val;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T minimumval(const T& a, const T& b, const Ts&... t) {
    const auto m = a < b ? a : b;
    if (sizeof...(t) > 0) {
        return minimumval(m, t...);
    }
    return m;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does the compiler want a `minimumval(int&)` at all given that it would never reach the said scenario being guarded by an `if` block?
2. What does constexpr do differently here?

Comment: Why do you spam in tags? Can't you decide which C++ version to use?

Comment: In regular `if` both branches are "instantiated" even if condition is always false...

Comment: so in `if (false) { return minimum(m); }`, `minimum(m)` should be valid.

Comment: Notice that [`std::min({ts...});`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) does the job.

Answer (score 2):

1. > Why does the compiler want a minimumval(int&) at all given that it would never reach the said scenario being guarded by an if block?

It's the same scenario as:

```
void existing_function();
void foo()
{
    if (true)
    {
        existing_function();
    }
    else
    {
        non_existing_function();
    }
}
```

`non_existing_function` must be declared, regardless if you reach the branch or not. The compiler must generate code to call it.

2. > What does constexpr do differently here?

Since constexpr if is evaluated at compile time, the language says that the branch that is not executed is discarded. It still needs to be valid syntax. So if you have a non template function that must be declared. But if you have a template then that template is not instantiated, that's why it compiles in your case: `minimumval` is a template.

Comment: If I follow correctly, without constexpr, the template will be instantiated including the basecase and hence I need legal code/function. With consexpr the template is not instantiated at all when the if branch evaluates to false. Is that so?

Comment: @NileshPatra yes